# Password entry only responds to Ctrl + D, and password cannot be read

Tags: ssh, password, openvpn, openwrt

I am trying to run `build-key-pkcs12 user` on my OpenWRT NSLU2, to generate some client keys for the users of my VPN. Everything runs normally until I get to the `enter export password` part, and the SSH terminal completely freezes. Enter does absolutely nothing, and the prompt just hangs, and accepts no input. I am using PUTTY under Windows 7.

I have been following [this guide.](http://www.frogiswrong.com/blog/articles/8/openvpn-on-openwrt-a-little-more-detail)

Telnet does exactly the same thing.

```
# cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.3.8 (blogic@Debian-60-squeeze-64-minimal) (gcc version 4.6.3 20120201 (prerelease) (Linaro GCC 4.6-2012.02) ) #1 Sun Mar 24 00:20:13 UTC 2013
```

Output of command:

```
root@OpenWrt:/etc/easy-rsa/keys# build-key-pkcs12 u
NOTE: If you run ./clean-all, I will be doing a rm -rf on /etc/easy-rsa/keys
Generating a 1024 bit RSA private key
.......++++++
...................++++++
writing new private key to 'u.key'
-----
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [UK]:
State or Province Name (full name) [(removed)]:
Locality Name (eg, city) [(removed)]:
Organization Name (eg, company) [N/A]:
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) [N/A]:
Common Name (eg, your name or your server's hostname) [u]:
Name [George]:
Email Address [test@localhost]:

Please enter the following 'extra' attributes
to be sent with your certificate request
A challenge password []:
An optional company name []:
Using configuration from /etc/easy-rsa/openssl-1.0.0.cnf
Check that the request matches the signature
Signature ok
The Subject's Distinguished Name is as follows
countryName           :PRINTABLE:'UK'
stateOrProvinceName   :PRINTABLE:'(hidden)'
localityName          :PRINTABLE:'(hidden)'
organizationName      :PRINTABLE:'N/A'
organizationalUnitName:PRINTABLE:'N/A'
commonName            :PRINTABLE:'u'
name                  :PRINTABLE:'George'
emailAddress          :IA5STRING:'test@localhost'
Certificate is to be certified until Aug  5 00:01:55 2025 GMT (3650 days)
Sign the certificate? [y/n]:y


1 out of 1 certificate requests certified, commit? [y/n]y
Write out database with 1 new entries
Data Base Updated
Enter Export Password:
```

This is where the terminal crashes. I also tried Windows 7 Telnet, and this does the same thing.

How can I fix this?

Is there another way to generate client keys without using this program?

**NOTE: Pressing Enter does nothing. The terminal does not respond to any input, including Ctrl + C**

**EDIT: Ctrl + D makes the terminal respond, but then I get `Can't read password`

Comment: What do you mean by “the terminal crashes”? What the word means is that the terminal goes away (i.e. PuTTY exits), but since you mention pressing Ctrl+D, I don't think that's what you mean. At the point where the prompt “Enter Export Password:” is shown, it's waiting for you to type a password. So type a password (it won't be displayed on the screen in case someone is watching over your shoulder) and press Enter. What happens next?

Comment: @Giles. I mean no input is accepted. I can type and press enter, but when I press enter nothing happens at all. The only thing I can press is Control + D and then that cancels the prompt.

Comment: So you don't even get “Verifying — Enter Export Password” when you press Enter? Does pressing Ctrl+J work instead? If not, run the command `tty` before `build-key-pkcs12`, it displays something like `/dev/pts/42` (change the number to match yours). When the command is sitting at the password prompt, open another terminal and run `stty -a </dev/pts/42` and post the output. Run `ps -t pts/42` (post the output), find out the latest process ID (say 1234), and run `strace -p1234`, then go back to the other terminal and type a **throwaway** password and press Enter. Post the strace output.